# How useful is the Weierstrass representation of minimal surfaces?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Weierstrass representation  of minimal surfaces says that if I have a holomorphic function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and a meromorphic function $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f g^2$ is holomorphic with $U$ being simply connected, then we have an integral representation of the minimal surface.

1. Now, this means that for $U = B (0,1)$ for example, we have a million possible pairs of homolomorphic functions $f,g$ defined on this set. So this should give us a million different minimal surfaces, is this correct?
2. We cannot control the shape of our surface or the domain its range in $\mathbb{R}^3$, as it is totally arbitrary how $f,g$ can be chosen. The only thing we said is that for a given minimal surface, we can find such a pair $f,g$, but normally you would be interested in the other question: Given some boundary in $\mathbb{R}^3$: How can I find a minimal surface? - This seems to be unanswered. - So I see no point in this Weierstraß representation.
3. Is it important that $U$ is simply connected? Let's consider the following "stupid" example $U = \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ $f=g=1$ . Can I still construct a minimal surface by the Weierstraß representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the [Weierstrass–Enneper representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%E2%80%93Enneper_parameterization) gives us infinitely many explicit examples of parametric minimal surfaces. This is what it does.
2. Then there are some things that it does not. It does not solve [Plateau's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau's_problem). Not surprising, since boundary value problems for nonlinear PDE are not expected to admit explicit solutions.
3. The representation still works in non-simply-connected domains, although the integrals involved in it may be multiply valued, making the representation more difficult to use. For example, the [helicoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid) has Weierstrass–Enneper representation defined on punctured plane, and involving the complex logarithm (see [these notes](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~shipman/47/volume42011/M641_MKilchrist_Packard.pdf)). As a result, the image of parametrization is topologically different from the domain: it is simply-connected.

[image: helicoid]

You can find the general form of W-E representation in section 9.3 of *[Harmonic Mappings in the Plane](http://books.google.com/books?id=EZLQw7bPX5kC)* by Duren.

In the specific case you mentioned, the functions $f,g$ have holomorphic extension to $\mathbb C$, which is simply-connected; the puncture at $0$ has no effect other than removing one point from the surface.